# Does the facebook http api have an endpoint for text posts?

Tags: html, facebook, http, hyperlink

Does the facebook http api have an endpoint for text posts?

Like the equivalent of the following share endpoint:

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://reflect.ridvan.org/how-can-we-stay-informed-about-covid-numbers/`

but for making a text based post (encoding the content). Say, something like this:

`https://www.facebook.com/poster.php?content=Hello_from_a_distance_Social_Media`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the Graph API for that, and authorize users with the correct permissions to post. Although, prefilling messages is not allowed in any case. The message must be 100% written by the user.